# Windows 7 - wireless but wired connection loses default gateway almost daily

Tags: windows-7, wireless-router, gateway

I'm using Windows 7 Professional with SP1.
I have a Virgin Super Hub (Netgear wireless router and modem combined).

I have a wireless connection to a laptop which is fine.

I have a wired connection to a desktop that is fine most of the time, but almost every day when I first turn it on I cannot access the internet.

- I right-click on the network icon in my task bar and click 'troubleshoot problems'.
- It goes through its diagnostics.
- It eventually comes up with ' the default gateway is not available' and 'fixed'.
- Then I can access the internet without issue for the whole
  day.

I've tried updating drivers, and using a static IP, but neither had any positive effect.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Strangely - I can access the internet at the moment (obviously) but I cannot access my router.  If I go to `192.168.0.1` I get a 'page does not exist' error.

I can ping bbc.co.uk but not with `-r 1` - with that I get timeouts.

How can my internet be working but I cannot communicate with my router?

EDIT:
Rebooted my router and now `192.168.0.1` works.  But pinging any address with `-r 1` times out.

Not sure if any of that is related to the actual issue - my default gateway getting "lost" every now and again.

Comment: Are you sure that is the IP of your router? And what do you mean "page does not exist", you get no response or you get a 404?

Comment: I will check that the address is correct - but I'm sure I've connected to it before now using that address.  Sorry the actual message I get on Chrome is "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 192.168.0.1"

Comment: See the edit to my question - I can access my router now that I have rebooted it, but still not sure about the original issue.